# Incorporating Regex in Get-ChildItem

Tags: regex, powershell

I want powershell to return files from a folder whose file name *starts with* `America` and has `csv` extension. The folder contains files for different countries with csv, excel and txt formats.

The following command returns the files that are `.csv` but how can I also incorporate `start with`  filtering to the below to get only `America` items?

`Get-ChildItem ("C:\Users\Documents\Sales") -Filter *.csv`

[image]

Comment: Add America to your filter, e.g. -Filter "America*.csv"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-Filter` cannot use regex, but it does support the use of the `*` wildcard.

As [RetiredGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101240/incorporating-regex-in-get-childitem#comment132530889_75101240) already commented, the easiest way to get the files that start with `America` and have the `.csv` extension is to use

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\Documents\Sales' -File -Filter 'America*.csv'
```

<sup>the switch `-File` will make sure you only recieve files, not folders as well</sup>

If you do need to filter using regex, you can only do that by piping the results through to a `Where-Object` clause.
Suppose you want all files starting with 'America' or 'Mexico' and do not want files 'Canada' or any other country in your results. Then you could do

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\Documents\Sales' -File -Filter '*.csv' |  # first return ony .csv files
Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^(America|Mexico)' }                     # then filter out all that do not start with America or Mexico
```

Regex details:

```
^                # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(                # Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
                 # Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      America    # Match the character string “America” literally (case insensitive)
   |
                 # Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      Mexico     # Match the character string “Mexico” literally (case insensitive)
)
```